# error 1093 mysql update query

Tags: mysql

so I am trying to run this sql:

```
UPDATE creature_template
SET
    subname = "Utgarde Keep Heroics",
    Health_mod = Health_mod * 45,
    mindmg = mindmg * 100,
    maxdmg = maxdmg * 100,
    Armor_mod = armor_mod * 4
WHERE entry IN (
    SELECT difficulty_entry_1
    FROM creature_template
    WHERE entry IN (
        SELECT id FROM creature WHERE map = 574
    )
);
```

But I am getting this error:

> [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'creature_template' for update in FROM clause

How am I supposed to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the same table that you use in the SELECT part in MySQL. You'll need to use a sub-query like below to create a temporary table in the nested sub-query and it will not count as the same table you are updating:

```
UPDATE creature_template
SET
    subname = "Utgarde Keep Heroics",
    Health_mod = Health_mod * 45,
    mindmg = mindmg * 100,
    maxdmg = maxdmg * 100,
    Armor_mod = armor_mod * 4
WHERE entry IN (
    SELECT difficulty_entry_1
    FROM (creature_template
    WHERE entry IN (
        SELECT id 
FROM creature ) as temp
WHERE map = 574
    )
);
```

See also MySQL documentation on [the UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Query syntax is wrong.

You can update the same table that is referenced in selcting the entry.
Check this link:

[MySQL DOCUMENT FOR THIS:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)